# How can I keep existing SVG shapes instead of replacing them?

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, nodes, viewbox

Every button press is suppose to be replacing existing text inside rect along with the id's. While keeping previous shapes and text in the viewbox. Instead it just replaces the existing shape and id and doesn't show old shape and id.  What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

```
<svg class="myViewbox" id="viewBoxId" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g></g>
</svg>
```

```
function myFunction(clicked_id) {   
    d3.select('g')
        .append('rect')
        .attr('id','node_block')
        .attr('x',50)
        .attr('y',20)
        .attr('rx',20)
        .attr('ry',20)
        .attr('width',145)
        .attr('height',95)
        .attr('transform','translate(0,-15)')
        .attr('fill','white')
        .style('stroke','black')
        .style('stroke-width',5);

    d3.select('g')
        .append('text')
        .text(clicked_id)
        .attr('id','node_name')
        .attr('x',0)
        .attr('y',15)
        .attr('transform','translate(105,43)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:
If you want to append new groups of rect/text, make your first selection the svg container.

Using the number of children as `index` for repositioning groups vertically, otherwise they overlap.

```js
function myFunction(clicked_id) {   
   const svg = d3.select('svg');
   const num_g_children = svg.node().children.length;
   const g = svg.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0,${num_g_children*95})`);
       
       g.append('rect')
        .attr('id','node_block')
        .attr('x',50)
        .attr('y',20)
        .attr('rx',20)
        .attr('ry',20)
        .attr('width',145)
        .attr('height',95)
        .attr('transform','translate(0,-15)')
        .attr('fill','white')
        .style('stroke','black')
        .style('stroke-width',5);

       g.append('text')
        .text(clicked_id)
        .attr('id','node_name')
        .attr('x',0)
        .attr('y',15)
        .attr('transform','translate(105,43)');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button onclick=myFunction(~~(10*Math.random()))>Test</button>
<svg class="myViewbox" id="viewBoxId" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: After testing this code I saw it replaced the existing group and didn't keep the original displayed still. Further analysis using the developer tool confirmed that the group was being replaced. My previous code added the SVG for the first button push and every other button push appended to that group. What i'm looking to do is append the entire group and every button push creates a new group that will append to that group then show all groups that have been created via a multiple button pushes.

Comment: @Daniel I didn't understand your question, so you want to append/add new rect/text group every time you push the button? so your initial code was almost there, please confirm if is it the behavior I'll update the response

Comment: Sorry about the way I worded the question.  Yes, I want to append a new rect/add rect every time I push a button. Thank you for helping.

Comment: **Update** Works almost perfectly. @cal_br_mar  I had dragging functionality and now it doesn't work. I was originally dragging the groups individually. Am I suppose to drag the node or group still?  Here's my drag code. `var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
 .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
  });
d3.selectAll('g').datum({x: 0, y: 0}).call(dragcontainer);`

Comment: **Update** Fixed the drag functionality.

Comment: I did not have enough reputation points to show votes yet and I definitely upvoted. Thank you very much for your help!